# Django + AngularJS + ajax POST = strange QueryDict

Tags: django, post, angularjs

In `services.js` I have:

```
return $resource('/item', {name: 'myname'}, {
    make_POST: {
        method: 'POST',
    },
    make_GET: {
        method: 'GET',
    }
});
```

In `views.py`:

```
@ajax_request
def v_item(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return {'success': request.POST['name']}
    return {'success': request.GET['name']}
```

When I do `make_GET`, everything's fine. But when I do `make_POST` I get this:

```
"Key 'name' not found in <QueryDict: {u'{}': [u'']}>"
```

What do I do wrong?

**UPDATE:**
Figured out, that POST works if I send params when I call `make_POST`:

```
Item.make_POST({name: 'myname'}, function(response) {
    $scope.success_POST = response.success;
});
```

And in `views.py` do such trick:

```
return {'success': json.loads(request.raw_post_data)['name']}
```

But why `$resource`'s params ane not sent?

Comment: What is @ajax_request decorator?

Comment: It checks for `request.is_ajax()` and dumps returning dict to json. It's from `django-annoying` lib

Comment: When I did same things with jQuery, POST worked, don't think that problem is in decorator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because angular will serialize you request into json and send json to server, not a form encoded data

Comment: I tried `json.loads(request.POST)`, it does not help. As you can see: `<QueryDict: {u'{}': [u'']}>`, so angular does not send any data at all

Comment: Yep, you need to send params when making request. And the params that you passing when creating a resource is a url params. See docs here :  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

Comment: Wow, now it makes sence. Thank you very very much! I don't know how much time I would spend trying to figure the problem out without your answer